# Product Shortcode for Woocommerce is not working properly

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

In Woocommerce I am using `[product_category]` shortcode this way:

```
[product_category per_page="60" columns="6" orderby="" order="" category="non-veg-cr"]
```

Now the products in `non-veg-cr` product category should be displayed on the page and it was working fine earlier in [this web site](http://www.ninni.in/chefs-restaurant/).

But now different products are showing on the page.

Please suggest me the solution for the same.